# Install Ubuntu 20.04 desktop on MSI Mortar M350 and Ryzen 5 1600x

Tags: 20.04, system-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu 20.04.02 on a machine with MSI Mortar M350 and Ryzen 5 1600x.

After checking the disks, the installation crashes , due to

> monitor not being able to change resolution to 1280x1080 at 60Hz

After 3 different displays and 2 video cards, it's the same result. So the displays are ok, and the video cards, too. Is it possible to install Ubuntu on that machine? Can anyone help with this?

Comment: I don’t understand where that warning is coming from, but have you tried booting with the `nomodeset` kernel parameter? See https://askubuntu.com/a/38834/287379

Comment: Check with the vendor for any motherboard firmware updates -- those may fix all sorts of problems.